# Sending a link with custom OpenURL scheme to others gets disabled by some email applications

Tags: ios, url, openurl

I have an iOS app and in info.plist I set a custom URL scheme so if someone opens up a URL starting with that scheme (protocol), my application gets opened and show the user, the proper content.

BTW I want to send users email containing a link with my scheme, so if they tap on the link they can see something in the application.

The problem is when I send the email some email applications make the link disabled because of the unknown scheme.

My question is how I could somehow solve the problem? or if it's possible to offer my app when a link with http protocol gets clicked? Then I could use http instead of custom scheme and afterward the links don't get disabled because of unknown protocol.

Answer (score 1):

HTTP Link -> Opened in Safari (most likely) -> Server redirects to Custom URL Scheme.

Comment: Thanks NinjaLikesCheez for your response, you mean I have to redirect the user to server then from there redirect again to custom URL Scheme? Is there any other better solution for it?

Comment: @MohsenAsfia that's probably the easiest way to get around the email client not linking the URL Scheme.